# Single Query that reflect in Different Database Engine like PSQL,Oracle,SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any tool or concept that work For the below case,

I have Table named Test in PSQL, SQL, Oracle server.IF I insert or Update or Delete the Data in a Table Test in PSQL, The result should update in the remaining SQL and Oracle. The same case when we do in SQL or Oracle.

Whatever change that happens in any DB Engine that reflects in the remaining Engine also.

Comment: SQL is a language, and psql is a command shell; presumably you mean SQL Server and PostgreSQL?

Comment: The only thing I understood here is something like cross-database synchronization ? Is that it?

Comment: The part "we do in SQL or Oracle" doesn't make sense. SQL is a query language that is used by the Oracle database (and every other relational database).

Comment: yes, I need that cross-database synchronization only between Different DB @g00dy

Comment: If with "psql" you actually mean "PostgreSQL" then you could use a foreign data wrapper between Postgres and Oracle